# Laravel form - show file upload progress, then redirect to view when uploading finishes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a laravel application which successfully uploads files. I need to show a progress bar when the files are uploading since users might upload videos and then redirect to a certain view when uploading finishes. 
I have tried a few solutions which actually worked but not to my taste. For example, i tried DropZone but i only upload one file and i don't need the drag and drop feature. 
The solution that worked and came close to what i wanted is using jquery.form plugin. But the problem with it was, i still want the form to submit and redirect to the next page when the file upload finishes. 
Meaning, when uploading finishes, i still want the next line to be executed

return redirect()->action('PostController@edit', $post->PostID);

Here is my Controller (PostController)

```
public function attachstore(Request $request, $PostID)
{

$post = Post::findOrFail($PostID);

if ($request->hasFile('TextFile')) {
    $TextName = "";

    $now = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $nowStr = $now->format("m-d-Y-H-i-s-u");

    $TextName =  $nowStr . '.' . $request->file('TextFile')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->file('TextFile')->move(base_path() . '/public/textuploads/', $TextName);
    $post->PostText = $TextName;  
}  


if ($request->hasFile('VideoFile')) {
    $VideoName = "";
    $now = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $nowStr = $now->format("m-d-Y-H-i-s-u");

    $VideoName =  $nowStr . '.' . $request->file('VideoFile')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->file('VideoFile')->move(base_path() . '/public/videouploads/', $VideoName);
    $post->PostVideo = $VideoName; 
}  

$post->Save();

return redirect()->action('PostController@edit', $post->PostID);
```

}

Here is my view (attach.blade.php)

```
   {!! Form::open(array('route' => array('posts.attachstore', $post->PostID), 'files' => true)) !!}
   <div class="col-md-12">    
    <div class="form-group">     
      {!! Form::file('TextFile', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">    
    <div class="form-group">     
      {!! Form::file('VideoFile', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
  </div>

  {!!Form::button('Next', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary finish col-md-4'))  !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I don't know whether this could be done without using ajax, but i'd prefer a solution which uses ajax only to report how much file the server has received or the client has sent. I don't want to upload the files using ajax, only an estimate of the transferred file size.

Comment: Dropzone can work and you can specify the maximum number of file, if you want only one file then set it to 1. And dropzone will use AJAX so javascript can handle the redirect after you get the upload response.

Comment: can the redirect be done without javascript? So the progress bar will be visible while the file is uploading and the redirect gets handled by the Controller (return redirect()->action('PostController@edit', $post->PostID);)

Comment: Dropzone progress will sow while the file is uploading. When the upload is done, you can then do the redirect stuff

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a dedicated library to achieve this instead of rewriting all of the code.

Try any of these or you'll get more if you google for other library and use whatever fits well.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/

https://github.com/zimt28/laravel-jquery-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

I use [blueimp fileupoad](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to achieve that.

They have a [great example](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html) with code of multiple file upload with upload progress. You can easily add the redirect in javascript as a callback.